# Create Facebook Audience using graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am Following this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api
and try to creating a blank audience.

I am using my account id and access token but I am getting this error
"Unsupported post request. Object with ID '692xxxxxxxx1141' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions"

```
from facebookads.adobjects.customaudience import CustomAudience
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount

FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token='EAAGbDDbxxxxxx')

ad_account = AdAccount(fbid='692xxxxxxxx1141')

params = {
    CustomAudience.Field.subtype: CustomAudience.Subtype.custom,
    CustomAudience.Field.name: 'My new CA',
    CustomAudience.Field.description: 'People who bought on my website',
}
audience = ad_account.create_custom_audience(params=params)
```

Answer (score -1):

Account ID starts with a prefix: ('act_')

```
ad_account = AdAccount(fbid='act_692xxxxxxxx1141')
```